# Getting 'id' of the current visible DIV

Tags: php, css

I have around 6 `div` on a page and only one of them needs to be visible at a time. During page load, I hide all the other divs except the first one.

Here's my HTML structure.

```
<div id="A1">
</div>

<div id="A2">
</div>

<div id="B1">
</div>

<div id="B2">
</div>

<div id="C1">
</div>

<div id="C1">
</div>
```

Here's what I do to hide them :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#A2").hide();
    $("#B1").hide();
    $("#B2").hide();
    $("#C1").hide();
    $("#C2").hide();
});
```

How would I get the ID of the **visible div**? I have tried :-

```
var current_div = $("div:visible");
current_div_id = current_div.attr('id');
```

**Output** :- *Undefined*

```
var current_div = $("div:visible");
current_div_id = current_div[0].id;
```

**Output** :- *Blank*

What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Silly question I know, BUT: You have included the jQuery javascript library havn't you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Ofcourse I did haha.

Comment: @Akshay You have the id "C1" twice in your html

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Posting a solution to help future peeps.

It seems that jquery is unable to find the current div using my above code. What I did is, added a common class to all the divs. Like this :-

```
<div id="A1" class="divs">
</div>

<div id="A2" class="divs">
</div>

<div id="B1" class="divs">
</div>

<div id="B2" class="divs">
</div>

<div id="C1" class="divs">
</div>

<div id="C1" class="divs">
</div>
```

And now I modified my JS in this way :-

```
var current_div = $(".divs:visible");
current_div_id = current_div[0].id;
```

And it **worked**. So if you're in the same problem, remember to have a common class for all the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var current_div = $("div:visible").attr("id");
      $( 'body'  ).text( current_div );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neowar2x/4/

Comment: Really not sure how this would be different than alerting `current_div`.

Comment: first line GET the id of the visible one, second line shows it (it's to chek if first statement works...); sorry, i did not read other answers.

Answer (score 0):

well, your code is working actually, and I can get `id` using both methods. You're missing something else here, check `console` what else do you get.

just one issue, you won't get consistent results as you've duplicate `id` on your page `C1`, twice.

```
<div id="A1">
    A1
</div>

<div id="A2">
    A2
</div>

<div id="B1">
    B1
</div>

<div id="B2">
    B2
</div>

<div id="C1">
    C1
</div>

<div id="C2">
    C2
</div>
<p id = "one"></p>
<p id = "two"></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#A1").hide();
    $("#B1").hide();
    $("#B2").hide();
    $("#C1").hide();
    $("#C2").hide();
});
var current_div = $("div:visible");
current_div_id = current_div[0].id;
$("#one").text("ID: "+current_div_id);
var current_div = $("div:visible");
current_div_id = current_div.attr('id');
$("#two").text("ID using second method: "+current_div_id);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dhqrngy/)**

Comment: @Akshay- did you check fiddle?